# Handling modal dialogs in automated test of wxPython application

Tags: testing, wxpython

How to handle dialogs that are opened whilst testing wxPython application?

As someone already had [a similar issue](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Unit%20Testing%20with%20wxPython):

> the problem is that as soon as the app starts a modal dialog, control
>   does not return until the modal dialog has exited, at which time it's
>   too late for the testing script to enter data into it

In general I'd like to write a test case for the following workflow:

1. user presses button "SomeProcessing"
2. in opened dialog user chooses "Selection 1" and presses OK
3. data is processed based on selection and compared against known result (`data_after_processing`)

How to do step 2 so that things would happen automatically (the example below opens `Dlg_GetUserInput` and waits for manual input)? It could be, that my understanding of GUI testing is flawed and that part 3 should not be considered as GUI testing? In that case I probably need the rewrite the code ...

Any suggestions welcome!

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label="SomeProcessing")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SomeProcessing, btn)

    def SomeProcessing(self,event):
        self.dlg = Dlg_GetUserInput(self)
        if self.dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            if self.dlg.sel1.GetValue():
                print 'sel1 processing'
                self.data_after_processing = 'boo'
            if self.dlg.sel2.GetValue():
                print 'sel2 processing'
                self.data_after_processing = 'foo'

class Dlg_GetUserInput(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.sel1 = wx.CheckBox(self, label='Selection 1')
        self.sel2 = wx.CheckBox(self, label='Selection 2')
        self.OK = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.sel1)
        sizer.Add(self.sel2)
        sizer.Add(self.OK)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

def test():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    mf = MyFrame(None, 'testgui')

    for item in mf.GetChildren():
        if item.GetLabel() == 'SomeProcessing':
            btn = item
            break

    event = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, btn.GetId())   
    mf.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(event)

    """
    PROBLEM: here I'd like to simulate user input 
    sel1 in Dlg_GetUserInput 
    (i.e. mf.dlg.sel1.SetValue())
    and check that 
    data_after_processing == 'boo'
    """

    mf.Destroy()

test()
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out one of these applications for GUI testing:

- http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/ldtp/cobra
- http://sikuli.org/

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution in case anyone should stumble on the same problem.

```
def test():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    mf = MyFrame(None, 'testgui')
    for item in mf.GetChildren():
        if item.GetLabel() == 'SomeProcessing':
            btn = item
            break

    def clickOK():
        dlg = wx.GetActiveWindow()
        dlg.sel1.SetValue(True)
        clickEvent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wx.ID_OK)
        dlg.ProcessEvent(clickEvent)

    event = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, btn.GetId())   
    wx.CallAfter(clickOK)
    mf.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(event)

    print 'data_after_processing:', mf.data_after_processing
    mf.Destroy()
```